# Aligning RadioButton and EditText on same line when having multiple rows

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to create a small list (3 rows) where there are one `RadioButton` and one `EditText` view on each row arranged horizontally. I want the radiobuttons to be in the same `RadioGroup`. I can't add the radio button and the edit text view to a linearlayout because then Android yells about the radiobutton having another parent. How can I solve this?

I am adding each row programatically:

```
mAnswerGroup.addView(radioButton, new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
mAnswerGroup.addView(editText, new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: In this case you may be better off not adding radio buttons to a radio group to achieve the layout you want. You can manually achieve the same behaviour as the radio group quite easily.

Comment: Okey, that was what I thought. I find the implementation of RadioGroup a little strange. It should not enforce restrictions on the design. All it should do is to maintain the exclusions etc. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, a `RadioGroup` won't work. You will have to manually handle the checked changes of the 3 `RadioButtons` because you need to make a LinearLayout and add a `RadioButton` and `EditText` inside it. You will have to manually uncheck the other radio buttons.

Set the onCheckedChangeListener of each `RadioButton` and handle then manually:
Implement `OnCheckedChangeListener` interface in your activity and do this in the `onCreate()`:

```
rb_1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
rb_2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
rb_3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

Then, override the `onCheckedChanged()` method of the interface:

```
@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton cb, boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked){
            //get the id of the checked button for later reference
            int id = cb.getId();

            /*
            * do what you want here based on the id you got
            */

            //uncheck the other RadioButtons
            rb_1.setChecked(id == R.id.rb_1);
            rb_2.setChecked(id == R.id.rb_2);
            rb_3.setChecked(id == R.id.rb_3);

        }
    }
```